# Is there a way to fix 'bad' surfaces in Solidworks?

Tags: solidworks, cad, computer-aided-design, surface-modelling

I'm trying to create a smooth blended fillet on the outer edge of a part with fillets around it's corners in Solidworks. The results I have are pretty much what I want it to look like but when I check out the curvature the surfaces look pretty patchy - does anyone know of a good way to solve this? Or has faced similar issues?
[image: desired edge fillet shape] [image: patchy surface curvature]

I've tried building these corners several different ways including lofts and boundary surfaces, but the way I have settled on uses a couple of filled surfaces just in the corners (areas shown in the image below). I've played around a lot with the edge settings and the ones shown are the best I can come up with. If anyone has any ideas on a different method of building the fillet that would also be appreciated.
[image: patches filled with filled surface]

Files: STEP of current surfaced fillet: http://www.filedropper.com/2021-06-25-filletedpart
STEP of unfilleted block: http://www.filedropper.com/2021-06-25-unfilletedpart

Comment: Are you able to share the file? This will really help to experiment, to give the best advice. Is this imported geometry, or a part you have made? why are you using surfacing tools to build these faces, rather than the fillet tools? Are you aware of variable radius fillets?

Comment: I can't share the original Solidworks file as it's for a client, but I've added a STEP of just that block which shows the surfaces, as well as a block that is the shape before applying any fillet/surfacing to the outer edge. I could just apply a fillet to the outer edge but it's not quite the shape I want as it gives a sharp point where the two fillets meet which I don't think looks great.

Comment: That sounds great - where do I find it? SE doesn't allow arbitrary attachments so you will need to share a link to e.g. Dropbox, WeTransfer, FileDropper, Google Drive etc.

Comment: Just editted the question and added a link to FileDropper, let me know if there is a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, looking at the "Filleted" file, it looks like you are trying to achieve the following:

1. Yellow = 1mm
2. Orange = 2.3mm
3. Red = 5mm

[image]

Your issue is primarily with order of operations. You need to do the yellow fillet *first*, in order to avoid the "sharp point where the two fillets meet" which you mentioned in your comment.

The file that you supplied described as "unfilleted" in fact had the yellow and red fillets already applied, so, adding the orange one after the fact does indeed look pretty rubbish:

[image]

I removed both of these using the "delete face" command to give a true 'blank slate', and then added the yellow radius first, before adding both red and orange together using a variable radius fillet.

[image]

P.S. The "Grey face" in the curvature evaluation *almost* runs 'curvature continuously' into the flat face next to it, but not quite. If you are worried about these fillets, it might be worth looking into that, too.

Comment: Ahh thank you! I can't believe I jumped straight to surfaces without even thinking about a different order, neat trick with the variable fillet as well thanks! If I had enough points to upvote your answer I would strongly

Comment: You can click 'accept answer' even if you can't upvote ☺️